# ksqlDB get message's value as string column from Json topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

There is a topic, containing plain JSON messages, trying to create a new stream by extracting few columns from JSON and another column as varchar with the message's value.

Here is a sample message in a topic_json

```json
{
  "db": "mydb",
  "collection": "collection",
  "op": "update"
}
```

Creating a stream like  -

```sql
CREATE STREAM test1 (
    db VARCHAR,
    collection VARCHAR
VAL STRING
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'topic_json',
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
  );
```

Output of this stream will contain only db and collection columns, How can I add another column as message's value - `"{\"db\":\"mydb\",\"collection\":\"collection\",\"op\":\"update\"}"`